# Should typo fix edits be rejected?

Tags: discussion

[This informal survey](http://wptavern.com/do-you-mistrust-a-company-that-misspells-wordpress) suggests that 60+ of WordPress users would not trust a WordPress company that misspells WordPress.

With [this edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/77734) I corrected "wordpress" and "Wordpress", plus a rather grating misspelling in the very title of the question ("differant"). However, my edit was rejected.

What is the policy in this case?

Comment: I am surprised that 60+% know what the correct spelling is ;)

Comment: In the meantime, WordPress is miscapitalised in your own profile text. ;)

Answer (score 8):

Personally, I wouldn't have rejected it as you actually *do* fix one of the typos ( `differant` to `different` in the title ). The proper spelling of wordpress isn't really a typo as much as a grammatical error and a minor one at that. Fixing the word "wordpress" doesn't make the question easier to read, easier to understand, easier to search as more times than not the question will still be conveyed the exact same way "WordPress" or "wordpress".

The WPSE is not a company and questions don't necessarily represent any company so I don't see the need to fix these minor spellings. That being said, if you are fixing something in the question / answer and also want to fix the spellings of wordpress then by all means do so but if that is all you're doing to a question or answer to improve it, it's probably not worth.

**TL;DR - It's "too minor" unless you're also fixing something specific.**

Answer (score 2):

My policy, as someone who edits a lot on many Stack Exchange site.

- Fixing grammar and spelling errors is good. Your correction of the spelling of *different* was a valuable edit and should not have been rejected. The reviewers were in error.
- Miscapitalisation of *WordPress* does not count as a grammatical or spelling error (unless it’s in all lowercase at the beginning of a sentence, of course). Feel free to change it (I do), but only if you’re also doing something else.

I am not a frequent user of this site, and I have found that SE sites vary in several respects, including in their perception of the value of edits. On some sites, minor typo corrections are usually accepted with thanks; on other sites you can turn an ungrammatical unreadable mess into a useful question and still be rejected. This is partly the whim of the individual reviewer, but there are also cultural differences between sites. (Math SE doesn’t like edits at all, no matter how valuable.)

However, my edits on this site, including typo fixes, have usually been accepted. Yours should have been too.

Comment: In the meantime, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/78597.